# Changing font in Farsi/Persian

Tags: fonts, languages

I'm typing my thesis in Farsi, and I'm using LiveTeX. I want to change my font in some parts of my documents. I checked most of the relevant questions and answers but unfortunately I couldn't find out my answer. There are two questions:

1. How can I change the font of some specific parts of my thesis?
2. What are font families?

I already used `{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont ... }` 
but it didn't work.

I used it as:

```
\documentclass[a4]{book}‎  
  ‎‎‎
‎\usepackage{‎graphicx}‎‎ 
\newenvironment{ppl}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}{‎Times New ‎R‎oman‎}‎
‎\textwidth =12cm‎ 
‎\textheight =19cm‎
‎‎‎\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}‎ ‎‎‎
‎‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎‎‎‎
‎\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}‎
‎\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}‎ 
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
\begin{document}
‎‎‎
من این همه را خودم نوشته ام و این یکی را می خواهم به صورت امتحانی در زیر با فونت دیگری بنویسم . ‎‎
‎
‎
\begin{‎ppl‎‎}‎
‎‎‎من این را به صورت امتحانی مینویسم . 
‎
\end{‎ppl‎‎}
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Do you mean change the typeface to *italic* and/or **bold**?

Comment: No I didn't . I mean changing the font , i.e. frome XB Zar To Times New Roman .

Answer (score 8):

You are using `xepersian` which is used with XeLaTeX, so you can use commands from the `fontspec` package (which is loaded automatically by `xepersian`) to change fonts or you can use commands from the `xepersian` package itself.

XePersian has a command `\deflatinfont` which allows you to create a command for the latin font you want.  For example, you want Times New Roman as the font, so you could do:

```
\deflatinfont\timesroman{Times New Roman}
```

You would then use it with:

```
{\timesroman Some Times Roman text here}
```

To make this an environment, (after defining the font as shown above) you can do:

```
\newenvironment{Times}{\timesroman}{\par}
```

and then use

```
\begin{Times}
...
\end{Times}
```

You can use `\deflatinfont` multiple times (with different command names) in your document to define other latin fonts.

Comment: @Negin: Note the use of [`\newenvironment{<nam>}{<begdef>}{<enddef>}`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-19.html). It takes 3 mandatory arguments, giving it a name `<nam>` and executing `<begdef>` at the start and `<enddef>` at the end. Effectively, `\begin{<nam>}`=`<begdef>` and `\end{<nam>}`=`<enddef>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\defpersianfont\Nastaliq{IranNastaliq}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{Nastaliq}{\N@stliq}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Nastaliq}

من ایران را دوست دارم

\end{Nastaliq}

\end{document}
```